# How do I change the email address associated with a google cloud project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Years ago we needed to use the Google maps APIs to provide a search service. I used my personal Gmail account to set it up and get it going.

Now that it's been running I'm receiving notifications about it to my personal account but I'd like them to go to my work account instead. I've associated my work account with my google account so I'm able to login with my work account to my gmail account. I then tried to invite my work account to the project and that seemed to work. However the project only lists my personal gmail account as a project owner. Is there any way to change this to my work account?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go to Google Cloud IAM and add the new email as a new user to the project.
Give the user the same roles/rights as the previous one (especially if it should be an Owner).
Then you can test everything with the new user.
If everything is okay, you can remove the old user from IAM.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that, however it's like google just sees my primary (personal) email address as the one associated with the project. I even tried logging in using my work email address, everything works fine but it still acts like it's my personal email address as the primary contact/user for the account.

Comment: What do you mean by "act as"? What do you see in your activity logs (in the home page, tab activity)